# django phantomjs(selenium) - write to www-data directory.(ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, phantomjs

Os: Ubuntu
user: someuser (ubuntu user)

I have a view that generates screenshot using phantomjs and saves to disk.

It is working for dircetories owned by 'someuser'. But, the static and media directory(accessible to nginx) is owned by 'www-data' and this phantomjs unable to write image to it.

Any solution ?

Let me know for more questions.

Comment: have you tried adding yourself (the user) into the www-data group?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data user (ubuntu user) #Add user to www-data group

sudo chown -R user:www-data path/to/static/media/directory
```

Hope this helps .